Pycharm disable splitting of search terms in Find
When searching for filenames in Find (double shift), Pycharm also returns to me results that would match if the search term would be split. For example searching for main, would also return the file with name MAn_IN_the_middle.py (check image).
How can I disable this? I couldn't find anything in the settings, on the web or in the documentation about this...
enter image description here
I couldn't find anything in the settings, on the web or in the documentation about this...
